# `quarto install tool` fails to make connection

Tags: r, quarto

I am trying to install a couple different PDF engines to find one that works best with one of the table libraries I'm using in a quarto book.

When I run `quarto install tool` from a Powershell session in the project root directory I return the following message:

```
[>] Inspecting tools
ERROR: TypeError: error sending request for url (https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/tinytex-releases/releases/latest): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (os error 10060)
```

I have the correct proxies for my organization (`http_proxy`, `https_proxy`) defined as OS environment variables *and* in the project `.Renviron` file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you can access https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/tinytex-releases/releases/latest from your browser? It's not blocked by your network?

Comment: @MrFlick, that's correct. When I hit that URL with Google Chrome, I get back a few hundred lines of JSON.

Comment: turned out this was caused by a poorly corrected proxy. the issue has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my proxy needed to be reconfigured to access the URLs being called to install software. The issue is resolved.