quarto ERROR: tlmgr returned a non zero status code
I tried to render a quarto test file format pdf , in backroundjobs I get this :
running xelatex - 1
command xelatex not found, attempting install
finding package for xelatex
> 1 package to install
> installing xelatex (1 of 1)
ERROR: tlmgr returned a non zero status code
Le chemin d'acc�s sp�cifi� est introuvabl

I tried to install tinytex from terminal :  I get this : ERROR: TypeError: error sending request for url (https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/tinytex-releases/releases/latest): error trying to connect: tcp connect
error: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu. (os error 10060)

might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74390681/quarto-install-tool-fails-to-make-connection

how can I reconfigure my proxy to access to the called URLs to be able to install the software please!
